# Automated build from Github private repositority on Docker Hub doesn't work

Tags: github, dockerhub

I'm trying to create an automated build on Docker Hub from a Github **private** repository.

- I linked my *Github* account with my *Docker Hub* account.
- I verified that the deploy keys provided by *Docker Hub* are created in my *Github* repository

But I still have an error. I'm not sure if it's related to **SSH keys** or **gitmodules**.

Here is the log I get (in *Build Details* tab in my *Docker Hub* repo) :

```
Starting to clone
Cloning into 'bsntx4mjvrqncsdvzcn7tqp'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'XXX.XX.XX.XX' to the list of known hosts.
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/logan-3722sdf9a9db5'
please ensure the correct public key is added to the list of trusted keys for this repository and the remote branch exists. (1)
```

Does anyone has the same error ?

**My solution :** I have solved my problem by removing the file vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/logan-3722sdf9a9db5 in my github repo. So the error about the public keys has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not with the key.

I don't know the exact issue. You can use the following command to sort the issue out.

```
git submodule update --init
```

The output of the command will be passed to

```
git rm --cached {{output}}
```

Push the commit.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I'm posting this as an "answer" instead (sorry!)

I have the same issue with Bitbucket, it fails to fetch from my submodule which is included in my main repo. I haven't been able to fix this issue yet. I even bough a paid subscription and added an automated build in hub.docker, hoping that would fix it, but nope..

`Starting to clone
Cloning into 'bokyrk3hkhspby5smhf6kby'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'xxx.xxx.xxx' to the list of known hosts.
Submodule 'lib/shared' (https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx_sharedlibs.git) registered for path 'lib/shared'
Cloning into 'lib/shared'...
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://xxx@bitbucket.org': No such device or address
Clone of 'https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx_sharedlibs.git' into submodule path 'lib/shared' failed
please ensure the correct public key is added to the list of trusted keys for this repository and the remote branch exists. (1)`

Comment: I have solved my problem by removing the file vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/logan-3722sdf9a9db5 in my github repo.

So the error about the public keys has nothing to do with it. It is really related to git but doesn't trigger errors when you use git, only when git is used by docker hub.

Comment: Just as an update, the issue for me was that my lib/shared submodule was private. Docker doesn't seem to like that. Long story short, I removed the submodule and now manually keep track of those shared files.

Answer (score 0):

Following procedure followed by me made it work:

Added my private key to local ssh through git bash.
Added my public SSH key to github. 
This ssh key was already available in my dockerhub.
So, I linked another public dockerhub userid (where automated build was successful) as a collaborator to this private automated build.

Answer (score 0):

For work with private repo, you should add ssh key from Docker Hub (showing on add auto build) to your github ssh keys.

Answer (score 0):

When the automated build fails the orange alert on the top of the build details can be a bit deluding:

> Build failed: please ensure the correct public key is added to the
>   list of trusted keys for this repository and the remote branch exists.
>   (128)

Even when you have set up you ssh keys this message always displays. You need to look at your Logs at the bottom of the build details to see more information if you know that you have set up your ssh keys for a private repo already.

For example your logs might say:

> fatal: no submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path
>   'my-app/my-blog'

or maybe it could be

> Dockerfile not found at ./my-app/Dockerfile

in your case you had a problem related to having the file `vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/logan-3722sdf9a9db5` in your solution which needed to be removed.